# Why do I keep getting "cannot find symbol" error?

Tags: java, arrays

I get the error saying "cannot find variable months". Maybe this is because the method cannot access the array months to find its length. I've used the main metod together with an additional method called SearchMethod.
Could someone please tell me how I could solve this? Here's my code

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class SearchStringM
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May"};

    String search = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the term you wish to search for ");

    SearchStringM x = new SearchStringM();
    x.SearchMethod(search);
    //String r = SearchMethod(search);
}

public static String SearchMethod(String search){ 
    boolean contains = false;
    for(int i=0; i<months.length; i++)
    {
        if(months[i].contains(search))
        {
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(contains)
    {
        System.out.println("This contains " + search);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This does not contain " + search);
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to understand what **local** variables are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare that variable above the main method so that you can use that variable across that class.

Answer (score 0):

hey write line no 6 `String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May"};` into your function `SearchMethod()` or define it on class level.
You are getting this error because it declared in main and you are using it in that method.

Answer (score 0):

`months` is **only** defined in the main function, thus SearchMethod can't use it, you have to send the variable via parameter to the funcion.

Try this:

Change:

```
public static String SearchMethod(String search){ 
...
```

to

```
public static String SearchMethod(String search, String[] months){
...
```

and

```
x.SearchMethod(search);
```

to

```
x.SearchMethod(search, months);
```

Or you can just declare `months` above the main method